# Pivot table column name and horizontal bar in Pivot Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-365, pivot-chart

My pivot table has a problem. 
As you can see,
the first column has a heading of "Row Labels" (in cell A10). 
I want it to say "Months".

[image: screenshot of Excel table and graph]

Also, I'd like to have a horizontal line appear
at an exact percentage in my chart. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

1 - Just overtype the text "Row Labels" with your desired text

2 - You would need a combination chart to add a line to a chart. Pivot charts are a lot less configurable than regular charts and may not support all you want to do. In that case, build a regular chart off the pivot table data. Then you can use a combination chart.

Comment: Holy mother! The first one was easy. Lol. Jeez... hahahahahaha. I think I tried and it didn't pick up my first attempt. Hehehehehe. Oookay. I'd give you +1 but I need 15 reps.

Comment: You don't need rep to accept an answer. Take the [tour] to see how.